# Never got answerd my questions properly , People digress it

Tags: support

When I asked my questions yet , I never get proper answered it , people digress it . I think to stop using this site. I thought it will too good to have some knowledge and help before I go to doctor. When I asked people digress it to something . I shouldn't ask here again. Thanks a lot. @-}--

Comment: It would help if you could say what question you are talking about

Comment: People digressed what I asked .

Comment: The simple thing is, if you are joining a community (and all SE websites are a based on user communities) and if this community has rules (and SE does) than you can comply or decide to go elsewhere. We have all been pointing you in the right direction, nicely. But we cannot change the policy on the questions that are off-topic for the reasons explained in detail in the [help] and here on meta. As for the discussion on placebo, if you google the phenomenon you will see that it actually was a partial answer to your question. To say more than that in a comment would be against the rules, sorry.

Comment: To avoid future misunderstandings, I recommend: [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you @-}--  I'll ask on-topic questions. Thanks a lot all of you.

Answer (score 7):

You currently have two questions on Health.SE:

https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4669/can-i-use-liver-tonic-without-prescription

And

https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5170/which-is-safer-and-better-treatment-for-imbalance-disorder

From what you write here, I am going to assume you are talking about the second. There are multiple issues with that question, which is why people were commenting and asking so much.

- as Lucky and I tried to explain to you, nobody can tell you what the best way to treat you is before you have an actual diagnosis. I did however link you to an NHS information page about the general classic of conditions you are asking about. If you had a question about one of those, you could have specified your question for that.
- as JohnP tried to explain to you, even with the actual diagnosis, the question is off-topic or at least very close to it. As explained [in the help center](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> If your question is requesting personal medical advice, it is off-topic and instead should be directed to your personal physician

- and, as explained by Carey Gregory, if your question is whether you should choose homeopathy as a treatment, you should ask whether that would work. The answer would be "no".

I am sorry that you seem to find this site unfriendly, but people have in fact tried to explain to you how to ask a better (and answerable) question. I, at least, didn't try to "disgress", I tried to find out what you were asking about and whether that was on-topic for the site.

Comment: My second question , when I'm telling I'm not talking about something else and they telling me that; I was asking about medicine but they was telling me about pain killer. Placebo ; even I wouldn't care it'd be placebo or not ; My question was by what I must travel bus or train , like that; I expect specific one but they didn't . I don't think there are something wrong with my question, but I can understand personal medical advice. Thank you .

Comment: @Swapnil I'm confused - where did anyone say anything about pain killers?

Comment: Sorry , I mean I had asked about medicine or what kind treatment I must choose allopathy or homeopathy and they was telling about place , does it make sense ? Why they telling about placebo ? When I asked about which way , they didn't answer properly with one "homeopathy" or "allopathy" They saying it'll be placebo or not (I said for an example pain killer not real treatment). I can't explain more about my question ; I tried to get advice and don't think really something wrong with my question. Thank You so much all of you @-}--

Comment: @YviDe - There are also three deleted questions, two deleted by community after being locked for off topic, and one self deleted question by the OP.